# How to run INstead of trigger on all my tables in my database with even field?

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

i just want to use a trigger instead of insert and update to run on all my tables?
how to do it?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use triggers on DML operations (so per table) as well as on the entire database (DDL trigger). I imagine the syntax is more or less the same for other systems.

The syntax for the first is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER name ON table
   [FOR/AFTER/INSTEAD OF]
   [INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE]
AS
BEGIN
--SQL statements
...
END
```

DDL triggers are not used as much, mostly for auditing but there are better ways to do audit. Anyway, check out [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like it is necessary to create trigger for each table in your database. You can dynamically create a SQL statement on the tables loop  and then run that command.

Simple example (Output results in text format)

```
DECLARE @triggerName nvarchar(50) = 'triggerName'
SELECT 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@triggerName) + ''')' + 
       ' IS NOT NULL DROP TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + 
       QUOTENAME(@triggerName) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       'CREATE TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' +
       QUOTENAME(@triggerName) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) + '.' + 
       QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       'INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       'AS' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       'BEGIN' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       '  SELECT ''your_logic''' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +      
       'END' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
       '' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)      
FROM sys.tables
```

Comment: oh i just have a little problem

Comment: what should i use instead of @dsql?
is it my data base name?

Comment: @user1998368 i deleted this variable, it isn't necessary.

Comment: @user1998368 You need to read these posts: How does accepting an answer work?
How does accepting an answer work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work